# Doctrine, In InvalidProxyDirectoryException.php line 18:

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PR5K.png)

Im using Doctrine in my custom project with PHP 7.4.6. When I`m trying to apply migration I get this error

```
[error] Migration app\migrations\Version20210113120851 failed during Pre-Checks. Error: "Provided directory "C:\Users\836D~1\AppData\Local\Temp" does not exist"

In InvalidProxyDirectoryException.php line 18:
                                                                          
  Provided directory "C:\Users\836D~1\AppData\Local\Temp" does not exist
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using windows, the problem could be in "vendor/friendsofphp/proxy-manager-lts/src/ProxyManager/FileLocator/FileLocator.php". To do migration you can just comment `$absolutePath = realpath($proxiesDirectory);` row in constructor and specify explicitly your temp directory path.
f.e.:

```
//$absolutePath = realpath($proxiesDirectory);
$absolutePath = 'C:\Temp';
```

Comment: O_O do not change code in your `vendor/` - it's just making stuff worse.